# Why does part of my scene get cut off when going into camera view?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

When I go into camera view, part of my scene gets cut off automatically. The render tab and shading tab also has part of my scene not visible but the scene is fine in all other modes.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting Clip Start to 0.01 or lower and End to 500 or higher. Does that solve the camera? What are the parts that are missing in the other tabs?  Do you have screenshots?

[image]